# SIMPLY DIFFICULT. The like button is not shown for some URLs

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I have three like tags with different URLs (all of them working, the same site):

1. http://www.sawbook.pl/
2. http://www.sawbook.pl/like_test.html
3. http://www.sawbook.pl/najszczesliwszy-dzien.html

Unfortunately there is only one like button!
Are my URLs banned!?
What's wrong?

Test page: http://www.sawbook.pl/like_test.html

```
<dl>
  <dt>http://www.sawbook.pl/</dt>
  <dd>
    <div class="fb-like"
         data-href="http://www.sawbook.pl/"
         data-layout="standard" data-action="like"
         data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dt>http://www.sawbook.pl/like_test.html</dt>
  <dd>
    <div class="fb-like"
         data-href="http://www.sawbook.pl/like_test.html"
         data-layout="standard" data-action="like"
         data-show-faces="true" data-share="true">
    </div>
  </dd>
  <dt>http://www.sawbook.pl/najszczesliwszy-dzien.html</dt>
  <dd>
    <div class="fb-like"
         data-href="http://www.sawbook.pl/najszczesliwszy-dzien.html"
         data-layout="standard" data-action="like"
         data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
  </dd>
</dl>
```

Comment: did you try using the same (working) url three times? just to see if it works.

Comment: Yes. It displays 3 buttons.

Comment: Facebook rarely bans individual URLs - usually it is the complete domain. (If any of those URLs were banned, you should get a message saying so if you try and post them on Facebook directly.) // The other two URLs from your example don’t even work when input directly in the Like button configurator. The Facebook URL that provides the like button loads with a status code 200 OK, but the content seems to be different from what a working Like button returns. I’d suggest you file a bug report. https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the age restriction for the app that is used on the page.
Currently each of Like buttons works fine.

Thank you CBroe for your help.
I found a solution while I reported the bug, by the way, I checked the application settings.